# Vary sizes of arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r

Let's say I have the array:

```
x <- array(1:50, dim = c(5, 5, 2)) # 5 rows, 5 columns, 2 levels 
x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   26   31   36   41   46
[2,]   27   32   37   42   47
[3,]   28   33   38   43   48
[4,]   29   34   39   44   49
[5,]   30   35   40   45   50
```

Each subarray in x is of the same size (5 x 5).

Is there a way to randomly vary the sizes of subarrays?

Something like

```
x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [, 6]
[1,]  21     26   31   36   41   46
[2,]  22     27   32   37   42   47
[3,]  23     28   33   38   43   48
[4,]  24     29   34   39   44   49
[5,]  25     30   35   40   45   50
```

The moved column can be placed anywhere, not just appended to the end. A swap routine comes to mind, but this is fundamentally different.

Comment: array can hold only a specific size of dimension

Comment: Normally you'd use a `list` of `arrays` for that.